# RN Firebase - How to check if the user accepted the permission for notifications on IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native-firebase

According to the official react-native-firebase [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.2.x/messaging/reference/messaging#[ios]-requestPermissions) you can use the method requestPermissions() for ios to prompt the user about accepting notifications, but how can I check if the user declined it or not since said method returns void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the docs incorrectly state that it returns void, it actually returns a promise that resolves with an object - we'll get the docs updated.

On iOS 9 or below, there's no way to tell whether the user accepted or rejected the permissions popup - in this case the object will have a property called `status` with a value of `"unknown"`

In all other cases the object will have a `granted` property which is a boolean value of true/false.

iOS <= 9: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/master/ios/RNFirebase/messaging/RNFirebaseMessaging.m#L291

iOS >= 10: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/master/ios/RNFirebase/messaging/RNFirebaseMessaging.m#L302

EDIT: I've updated the docs to reflect the above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!